# How to add new argument with default value to function which accepts varargs in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, overloading, variadic-functions, default-arguments

Let's say initially I have function:

```
fun foo(arg1: Int, vararg strings: String) {
}
```

and there are a lot of calls like this:

```
foo(1, "a", "b", "c")
```

Now I want to add additional argument with default value to avoid need  changing existing calls:

I tried

```
fun foo(arg1: Int, arg2: Double = 0.0, vararg strings: String) {
}
```

But it breaks existing calls:

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Double
> Found:
> String

Also I've found this way:

```
fun foo(arg1: Int, vararg strings: String, arg2: Double = 0.0) {
}
```

It doesn't break existing calls but if I want to use custom value for `arg2` I have to name argument explicitly:

```
foo(1, "a", "b", "c", arg2 = 0.0)
```

because following call leads to compile error:

```
foo(1, "a", "b", "c", 0.0)
```

Is there better option for my use case ?

Comment: "It breaks existing calls." You mean binary incompatible, right? Also what platform are you on? JVM?

Comment: @Sweeper I mean just compile error

Comment: Oh you're right. I didn't expect this to be source incompatible.

Comment: @Sweeper me too) So I've decided to ask

Comment: I think you'd just have to add a new overload.

Comment: that is the expected solution to your issue sadly. [The docs](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/vararg-function-parameter-with-default-value/5355) say the same thing `Only one parameter can be marked as vararg. If a vararg parameter is not the last one in the list, values for the subsequent parameters can be passed using named argument syntax, or, if the parameter has a function type, by passing a lambda outside the parentheses.`

Comment: Have you tried just refactoring using IntelliJ or some other IDE. Rightclick the function > Refactor > Change Signature. Here you can add new parameters and add default arguments which will be automatically inserted at every call.

Comment: @Sweeper could you please share a bit more details about solution with overloading ?

Comment: @Burdui I am also worry about amount of pull request changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create a new overload, instead of using parameters with default values.

```
// add this new overload
fun foo(arg1: Int, arg2: Double, vararg strings: String) {
    // move the implementation to the new overload...
}

fun foo(arg1: Int, vararg strings: String) {
    // the old overload will call the new overload and pass some default values
    foo(arg1, 0.0, *strings)
}
```